# Install nuget package to all projects in a solution using dotnet cli commands

Tags: nuget, dotnet-cli

I know this can be done via Visual Studio -> Package Manager. But I wanted to know if there is a command or a workaround to install the nuget package to all the projects in a solution using dotnet CLI.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
dotnet add projectPath/projectName package MediatR --version 10.0.1;
```

[Link to nuget for package MediatR](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediatR)

Answer (score 0):

You can add new properties to all projects in a solution by doing the following:

- Add a `Directory.Build.Props` file to the solution root. *Here is some sample content that adds SonarAnalyzer.*

```
<Project>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference 
      Include="SonarAnalyzer.CSharp" 
      Version="9.16.0.82469"
      PrivateAssets="all"
      Condition="$(MSBuildProjectExtension) == '.csproj'" 
    />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

- Run `dotnet restore` in the solution root.

Here is the documentation for [Directory.Build.props and Directory.Build.targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-by-directory?view=vs-2022#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets).